# Flutter: I can't pull data with Mysql1

Tags: android, mysql, flutter

I recently started Flutter. I want to make a simple contacts application with "mysql1" but I failed to pull the data. I installed the MySQL plugin in VS Code and I can see the table I created, but the application always returns "no data". After some research, I learned that it is better to do it with the API. But I still want to know why this is not working. Thank you.

Model: contact_model.dart

```
 class ContactModel {
      int? id;
      String? name;
      String? lastName;
      String? phoneNumber;
    
      ContactModel(this.id, this.name, this.lastName, this.phoneNumber);
    }
```

View: homepage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/contact_model.dart';
import '../../products/utility/database_helper.dart';
import 'add_data.dart';

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  bool state = false;

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final DatabaseOperations _databaseOperations = DatabaseOperations();
  List<ContactModel> allData = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("IContacts"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          const Duration(seconds: 3);
          // ignore: avoid_print
          print("value");
          Navigator.push<bool>(
              context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => data_add()));
        },
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: allData.isNotEmpty
              ? ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: allData.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(allData[index].name ?? "error"),
                      subtitle: Text(allData[index].phoneNumber ?? "error"),
                      leading: Text(allData[index].id.toString()),
                      trailing: IconButton(
                          tooltip: "Delete Person",
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                          onPressed: () async {}),
                    );
                  })
              : const Text("no data")),
    );
  }

  void fetchData() async {
    allData = await _databaseOperations.fetchData();
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

DatabaseHelper: database_helper.dart

```
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';
import '../../feature/models/contact_model.dart';

class DatabaseOperations {
  final String _host = 'localhost';
  final int _port = 3306;
  final String _user = 'root';
  final String _password = '';
  final String _db = 'contact_app';

  DatabaseOperations();
  Future fetchData() async {
    try {
      final connect = await MySqlConnection.connect(ConnectionSettings(
          host: _host, port: _port, user: _user, password: _password, db: _db));

      List<ContactModel> myList = [];
      var dataList = await connect.query('SELECT * FROM `contacts_db`');

      for (var item in dataList) {
        myList.add(ContactModel(
            item["id"], item["name"], item["lastName"], item["phoneNumber"]));
      }
      await connect.close();
      return myList;
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  Future<bool> addData(
      {required String name,
      required String lastName,
      required String phoneNumber}) async {
    try {
      final connect = await MySqlConnection.connect(
        ConnectionSettings(
            host: _host,
            port: _port,
            user: _user,
            password: _password,
            db: _db),
      );

      await connect.query(
          "insert into contacts_db (name,lastName,phoneNumber) values (?,?,?)",
          [name, lastName, phoneNumber]);
      await connect.close();
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> updateData(
      {required int id,
      required String name,
      required String lastName,
      required String phoneNumber}) async {
    try {
      final connect = await MySqlConnection.connect(
        ConnectionSettings(
            host: _host,
            port: _port,
            user: _user,
            password: _password,
            db: _db),
      );


      await connect.query(
          "update contacts_db set name=? , lastName=? , phoneNumber = ? where id = ?",
          [name, lastName, phoneNumber, id]);
      await connect.close();
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> deleteData({required int id}) async {
    try {
      final connect = await MySqlConnection.connect(
        ConnectionSettings(
            host: _host,
            port: _port,
            user: _user,
            password: _password,
            db: _db),
      );


      await connect.query('delete from contacts_db where id=?', [id]);
      await connect.close();
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Debug Console :

```
E/flutter (27691): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<ContactModel>'
E/flutter (27691): #0      _HomePageState.fetchData
package:rehber_uygulamasi/…/view/homepage.dart:58
E/flutter (27691): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (27691):
Application finished.
Exited (sigterm)
```

**_HomePageSate.fetchData package:rehber_uygulamasi...homepage.dart:58 :

```
  void fetchData() async {
    allData = await _databaseOperations.fetchData();
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My assumption: Your `fetchData()` method is throwing an exception. You are catching it, but not doing anything with it. When throwing the exception your method basically returns nothing, hence the error is saying `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<ContactModel>'`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm new to Flutter so I'm not sure what to do, any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: @byuksekdag You probably should log the Exception and see what is going wrong. Other than that (if this should be recoverable) you probably need to return an empty List of `ContactModel` in the `catch` block.